# Is it necessary to set a minimum time to allow the next Rewarded Ad to appear since the last Rewarded Ad finish

Tags: admob, admob-rewardedvideoad, rewardedvideoad

I am thinking of integrating Rewarded Ad into the app (the first time I do it), so I have 2 questions:

1. My app uses **Banner Ad** throughout the app lifecycle, so if I add a `button` for the user to choose to view the **Rewarded Ad**, is it a violation? because from the moment the user sees the select view **Rewarded Ad** button => still shows the **Banner Ad** => presses to watch **Rewarded Ad** `button` => switches to a video ad => back to the app => **Banner Ad** shows up immediately.
2. Is it necessary to set a minimum time to allow the next **Rewarded Ad** to appear *(eg. after x seconds)* since the last **Rewarded Ad** finish? I tried searching on the internet and didn't find this information, so let's say the app has 5 free gifts to open by viewing the rewarded Ad for each gift => the user finished watching the video ad for the first gift *(at the same time the app reloads new **Rewarded Ad**)* => back to the app => User clicks **Rewarded Ad** `button` to continue watching video ad for second gift immediately, and so on to 5th gift, will it be violated?

Thanks